# display frame <PRIV> in mp3/wav

Tags: mp3

I have mp3 files where they have been edited by a proprietary software of the id3v2 tag information stored in private frames . Is there a solution to be able to trace the name of the field with which it was stored? I would like to be able to access this field with the MP3Tag software to be able to read that value and move it to another tag field to convert archives from one software to another.

is there a solution?

Comment: What programming/scripting language are you using to do this? and have you tried to dump all id3v2 tags from your file?

Comment: No I could not do the script for this I'm looking for help.
I tried various software to read mp3 tags on the net but nothing that reads me the values of private tags (they are just private for this) :)

Comment: have you tried something like what is recommended here: https://superuser.com/questions/364082/program-to-dump-id3-tag-structure

Comment: I had already tried something described in that post but with poor results, or it is I who do not understand how to do ...

one of the many files in question and downloadable here:
[link] www.iscriviti.altervista.org/Queen%20-%20We%20Will%20Rock%20You.mp3

if you want to do some tests I'm interested in custom fields

start, intro, outro, end, fadeout, start refrain, end refrain

Comment: nothing to do? there are no hopes?

Comment: If you open the .mp3 in an editor and look at the last two lines, you will find the tag info. I think that the ones you are looking for are encoded in a way I cannot deduce from the file. could you verify that the data IS stored in the file? can you open it with the tool that created it, but a different machine and get the same info?

Comment: I read a little at http://id3.org/Developer%20Information and apparently they have a complete list of tags, and a .net program (2 years old) you could try to run (https://github.com/judwhite/IdSharp)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your file, and tried to run the software at beaglebuddy.com on it. The output from a modified `Basic.java` (I removed the part writing new data to the mp3) is below.

This output is based on the "known tags" included in the program. As far as I can deduce, there are two frames where there is the option of it being private, but it is not, so potentially, if you update the source with the information about how to read the private tags, you can get a working program, that can do as you want.

```
mp3 file.....: Y:\mp3reader\Queen-WeWillRockYou.mp3
mp3 file size: 2903308 bytes
audio size...: 2901089 bytes
codec........: MPEG 1 Layer III
bit rate.....: 192 kbits/s
bit rate type: CBR
frequency....: 44100 hz
channel mode.: Joint Stereo
ID3v2.4 tag..: ID3v2.4 tag
   num frames: 8
   tag size..: 171 bytes
   padding...: 2048 bytes
ID3v2.4 tag header
   bytes..................: 10 bytes
                            0x49 0x44 0x33 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11 0x21 
   version................: ID3v2.4
   tag size...............: 2209 bytes
   unsynchronization......: false
   extended header present: false
   experimental indicator.: false
   footer present.........: false
ID3v2.4 frame: ALBUM_TITLE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x41 0x4C 0x42 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TALB: ALBUM_TITLE - album/movie/show title
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 19
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 19 bytes
             0x03 0x6E 0x65 0x77 0x73 0x20 0x4F 0x66 0x20 0x54 0x68 0x65 0x20 0x57 0x6F 0x72 
             0x6C 0x64 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: news Of The World
ID3v2.4 frame: LEAD_PERFORMER
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x50 0x45 0x31 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TPE1: LEAD_PERFORMER - lead performer(s)/soloist(s)
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 7
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 7 bytes
             0x03 0x51 0x55 0x45 0x45 0x4E 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: QUEEN
ID3v2.4 frame: CONTENT_TYPE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x43 0x4F 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TCON: CONTENT_TYPE - content type
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 6
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 6 bytes
             0x03 0x52 0x4F 0x43 0x4B 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: ROCK
ID3v2.4 frame: LANGUAGE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x4C 0x41 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TLAN: LANGUAGE - language(s)
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 9
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 9 bytes
             0x03 0x45 0x4E 0x47 0x4C 0x49 0x53 0x48 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: ENGLISH
ID3v2.4 frame: SONG_TITLE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x49 0x54 0x32 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TIT2: SONG_TITLE - title/songname/content description
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 18
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 18 bytes
             0x03 0x57 0x45 0x20 0x57 0x49 0x4C 0x4C 0x20 0x52 0x4F 0x43 0x4B 0x20 0x59 0x4F 
             0x55 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: WE WILL ROCK YOU
ID3v2.4 frame: TRACK_NUMBER
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x52 0x43 0x4B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TRCK: TRACK_NUMBER - track number/position in set
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 3
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 3 bytes
             0x00 0x31 0x00 
   encoding: 0 - ISO-8859-1
   text....: 1
ID3v2.4 frame: RECORDING_TIME
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x44 0x52 0x43 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TDRC: RECORDING_TIME - recording date/time
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 6
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 6 bytes
             0x00 0x31 0x39 0x37 0x37 0x00 
   encoding: 0 - ISO-8859-1
   text....: 1977
ID3v2.4 frame: USER_DEFINED_TEXT_INFORMATION
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x58 0x58 0x58 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0D 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TXXX: USER_DEFINED_TEXT_INFORMATION - user defined text information frame
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 13
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: user defined text information
   bytes......: 13 bytes
                0x03 0x49 0x4E 0x54 0x52 0x4F 0x00 0x31 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x00 
   encoding...: 3 - UTF-8
   description: INTRO
   text.......: 12000
ID3v2.4 tag footer: none
mpeg audio frame
   file position......: 2219
mpeg audio frame header
   size............: 4
   bytes...........: 0xFF 0xFA 0xB2 0x40 
   MPEG version....: MPEG 1
   MPEG layer......: Layer III
   protected.by CRC: true
   bit rate........: 192 kbit/s
   frequency.......: 44100 hz
   frame is padded.: true
   private bit.....: false
   channel mode....: Joint Stereo
   mode extension..: intensity stereo: off, MS stereo: off
   copyrighted.....: false
   original media..: false
   emphasis........: None
   frame size......: 627 bytes
   num samples.....: 1152
   side info size..: 32 bytes
mpeg audio frame side information
   size.: 32 bytes
   bytes: 0x00 0x00 0x04 0xE6 0x42 0xBE 0xE8 0xC6 0x42 0xE0 0x59 0xC5 0xB7 0xCD 0x18 0x63 
          0x5A 0x40 0x28 0x01 0x14 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x25 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x04 
mpeg audio frame audio samples
   size.: 589 bytes
ID3v1.0 tag
   file position: 2903180
   title........: WE WILL ROCK YOU
   artist.......: QUEEN
   album........: news Of The World
   year.........: 1977
   comment......: news Of The World
   track........: 0
   genre........: 0 - Blues
codec..............: MPEG 1 Layer III
bit rate...........: 192 kbits/s
bit rate type......: CBR
frequency..........: 44100 hz
audio duration.....: 0 s
audio size.........: 2901089 bytes
album..............: news Of The World
artist.............: null
contributing artist: QUEEN
lyrics by..........: null
music by...........: null
picture............: null
publisher..........: null
rating.............: 0
title..............: WE WILL ROCK YOU
track #............: 1
year recorded......: 1977
lyrics.............: null

mp3 file.....: Y:\mp3reader\Queen-WeWillRockYou.mp3
mp3 file size: 2903308 bytes
audio size...: 2901089 bytes
codec........: MPEG 1 Layer III
bit rate.....: 192 kbits/s
bit rate type: CBR
frequency....: 44100 hz
channel mode.: Joint Stereo
ID3v2.4 tag..: ID3v2.4 tag
   num frames: 9
   tag size..: 171 bytes
   padding...: 2048 bytes
ID3v2.4 tag header
   bytes..................: 10 bytes
                            0x49 0x44 0x33 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11 0x21 
   version................: ID3v2.4
   tag size...............: 2209 bytes
   unsynchronization......: false
   extended header present: false
   experimental indicator.: false
   footer present.........: false
ID3v2.4 frame: ALBUM_TITLE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x41 0x4C 0x42 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TALB: ALBUM_TITLE - album/movie/show title
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 19
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 19 bytes
             0x03 0x6E 0x65 0x77 0x73 0x20 0x4F 0x66 0x20 0x54 0x68 0x65 0x20 0x57 0x6F 0x72 
             0x6C 0x64 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: news Of The World
ID3v2.4 frame: LEAD_PERFORMER
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x50 0x45 0x31 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TPE1: LEAD_PERFORMER - lead performer(s)/soloist(s)
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 7
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 7 bytes
             0x03 0x51 0x55 0x45 0x45 0x4E 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: QUEEN
ID3v2.4 frame: CONTENT_TYPE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x43 0x4F 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TCON: CONTENT_TYPE - content type
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 6
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 6 bytes
             0x03 0x52 0x4F 0x43 0x4B 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: ROCK
ID3v2.4 frame: LANGUAGE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x4C 0x41 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x09 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TLAN: LANGUAGE - language(s)
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 9
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 9 bytes
             0x03 0x45 0x4E 0x47 0x4C 0x49 0x53 0x48 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: ENGLISH
ID3v2.4 frame: SONG_TITLE
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x49 0x54 0x32 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TIT2: SONG_TITLE - title/songname/content description
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 18
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 18 bytes
             0x03 0x57 0x45 0x20 0x57 0x49 0x4C 0x4C 0x20 0x52 0x4F 0x43 0x4B 0x20 0x59 0x4F 
             0x55 0x00 
   encoding: 3 - UTF-8
   text....: WE WILL ROCK YOU
ID3v2.4 frame: TRACK_NUMBER
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x52 0x43 0x4B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TRCK: TRACK_NUMBER - track number/position in set
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 3
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 3 bytes
             0x00 0x31 0x00 
   encoding: 0 - ISO-8859-1
   text....: 1
ID3v2.4 frame: RECORDING_TIME
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x44 0x52 0x43 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TDRC: RECORDING_TIME - recording date/time
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 6
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 6 bytes
             0x00 0x31 0x39 0x37 0x37 0x00 
   encoding: 0 - ISO-8859-1
   text....: 1977
ID3v2.4 frame: USER_DEFINED_TEXT_INFORMATION
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x54 0x58 0x58 0x58 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0D 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TXXX: USER_DEFINED_TEXT_INFORMATION - user defined text information frame
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 13
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: user defined text information
   bytes......: 13 bytes
                0x03 0x49 0x4E 0x54 0x52 0x4F 0x00 0x31 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x00 
   encoding...: 3 - UTF-8
   description: INTRO
   text.......: 12000
ID3v2.4 frame: LENGTH
frame header
   bytes..................: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
   frame type.............: TLEN: LENGTH - length of the song (in ms)
   frame header size......: 10
   frame body size........: 0
   tag  alter preservation: false
   file alter preservation: false
   read only..............: false
   compression............: false
   encryption.............: false
   grouping identity......: false
   uncompressed size......: 0
   encryption method......: 0
   unsynchronized.........: false
   data length indicator..: 0
   group Id...............: 0
frame body: text information
   bytes...: 0 bytes

   encoding: 0 - ISO-8859-1
   text....: 120000
ID3v2.4 tag footer: none
mpeg audio frame
   file position......: 2219
mpeg audio frame header
   size............: 4
   bytes...........: 0xFF 0xFA 0xB2 0x40 
   MPEG version....: MPEG 1
   MPEG layer......: Layer III
   protected.by CRC: true
   bit rate........: 192 kbit/s
   frequency.......: 44100 hz
   frame is padded.: true
   private bit.....: false
   channel mode....: Joint Stereo
   mode extension..: intensity stereo: off, MS stereo: off
   copyrighted.....: false
   original media..: false
   emphasis........: None
   frame size......: 627 bytes
   num samples.....: 1152
   side info size..: 32 bytes
mpeg audio frame side information
   size.: 32 bytes
   bytes: 0x00 0x00 0x04 0xE6 0x42 0xBE 0xE8 0xC6 0x42 0xE0 0x59 0xC5 0xB7 0xCD 0x18 0x63 
          0x5A 0x40 0x28 0x01 0x14 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x25 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x04 
mpeg audio frame audio samples
   size.: 589 bytes
ID3v1.0 tag
   file position: 2903180
   title........: WE WILL ROCK YOU
   artist.......: QUEEN
   album........: news Of The World
   year.........: 1977
   comment......: news Of The World
   track........: 0
   genre........: 0 - Blues
```

Answer (score 0):

JoSSte
Thank you very much for your help.
So let's do it, since you managed to retrieve information from mp3 files. Even if I tried to read all I can not find the information I need.

I put in this file * .RAR >>>> www.iscriviti.altervista.org/MP3_PRIV_TAG.rar

TWO MP3 files, the same song only that one is Original, with only primary tags edited by the Ripping program (media player), and the other file has been edited with the Software that generates the PRIVATE TAGS .

So at least I think it's easier to compare and see which lines of code are added by private tag software.

I hope you can go back to the data or better to the name of the labels where the data that interest me are stored.

I tried to use those software, files that you have linked but I honestly do not understand how to get them started.